# distance calculation in python for google earth coordinates

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Hi I have a kml file called Placemark and 4 nodes (placemarks) that are located in an area on Google Earth. Each placemark-node has a longitude and a latitude.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>placemarks.kml</name>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>placemarks</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Placemark>
            <name>node0</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>21.78832062146911</longitude>
                <latitude>38.28791526390673</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>0.001539813336055052</heading>
                <tilt>44.99941206765101</tilt>
                <range>990.2435222326291</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>21.78400936610002,38.2874355527483,67.51641688336248</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>node1</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>21.78832062146911</longitude>
                <latitude>38.28791526390673</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>0.001539813336055052</heading>
                <tilt>44.99941206765101</tilt>
                <range>990.2435222326291</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>21.78453228393861,38.28690995466475,67.51641688336248</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>node2</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>21.78832062146911</longitude>
                <latitude>38.28791526390673</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>0.001539813336055052</heading>
                <tilt>44.99941206765101</tilt>
                <range>990.2435222326291</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>21.7848823502596,38.2869152766261,67.51641688336248</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>node3</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>21.78832062146911</longitude>
                <latitude>38.28791526390673</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>0.001539813336055052</heading>
                <tilt>44.99941206765101</tilt>
                <range>990.2435222326291</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>21.78459887820567,38.28740826552452,67.51641688336248</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

What I want is to calculate the distance between node0 and node2,3,4... (keeping node0 constant in the distance function) and then, print the results.

By using the code below: (I need to modify it in order to have the output below)

```
 # adapted from haversine.py <https://gist.github.com/rochacbruno/2883505>
    # see also <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula>
    from math import atan2, cos, sin, sqrt, radians

    def calc_distance(origin, destination):
        """great-circle distance between two points on a sphere
           from their longitudes and latitudes"""
        lat1, lon1 = origin
        lat2, lon2 = destination
        radius = 6371 # km. earth

        dlat = radians(lat2-lat1)
        dlon = radians(lon2-lon1)
        a = (sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(radians(lat1)) * cos(radians(lat2)) *
             sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2))
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
        d = radius * c

        return d

    from xml.dom import minidom

    xmldoc = minidom.parse("placemarks.kml")
    kml = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("kml")[0]
    document = kml.getElementsByTagName("Document")[0]
    placemarks = document.getElementsByTagName("Placemark")

    nodes = {}
    for placemark in placemarks:
        nodename = placemark.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.data[:-1]
        coords = placemark.getElementsByTagName("coordinates")[0].firstChild.data
        lst1 = coords.split(",")
        longitude = float(lst1[0])
        latitude = float(lst1[1])
        nodes[nodename] = (latitude, longitude)
```

Ang get an output like:

```
node1: (21.78453228393861, 38.28690995466475), distance from node0: 
node2: (21.78488235025960, 38.28691527662610), distance from node0: 
node3: (21.78459887820567, 38.28740826552452), distance from node0:
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you collect nodes extracted from the KML file, the names of nodes, as you extract them from the XML, are always the same, so when you try to store it in the dictionary `nodes` you get only one point in the end. Here is a corrected script (only the last part, which needed to be be fixed), which I think does what you require (please tell us if it's not the case and you need something else):

```
nodes = {}
for placemark in placemarks:
    nodename = placemark.getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.data
    coords = placemark.getElementsByTagName("coordinates")[0].firstChild.data
    lst1 = coords.split(",")
    longitude = float(lst1[0])
    latitude = float(lst1[1])
    nodes[nodename] = (latitude, longitude)

for n in nodes:
    if n == 'node0':
        continue
    print n, nodes[n], 'distance from node0:', calc_distance(nodes['node0'], nodes[n])
```

Here is the output:

```
node1 (38.28690995466475, 21.78453228393861) distance from node0: 0.074152874049
node3 (38.28740826552452, 21.78459887820567) distance from node0: 0.0515409901388
node2 (38.2869152766261, 21.7848823502596) distance from node0: 0.0956671636024
```